# params[:id] is a relation object when redirecting to edit page from new page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, nested

I am checking if a user already left a review, and redirect to edit their review, rather than go to the new review page.

My implementation is resulting in `params[:id]` being a relation object

**review_controller.rb**

```
  def new
    @review = Review.new
    # Check if user already has a review for this park, and redirect to edit review path if so.
    if user_signed_in?
      @existing_review = Review.of_park(@park.id).by_user(current_user.id)
      if @existing_review
        redirect_to edit_park_review_path(@park, @existing_review)
        binding.pry
      end
    end

  end

  private
    def set_review
      @review = Review.find(params[:id])  #Error here 

    end
```

on that line I get this in the browser

```
Couldn't find Review with 'id'=#<Review::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x857fb98>
```

I thought if I am providing the correct arguments to the edit path `(@park, @existing_review)`, then the `@existing_review` object would act to provide the `:id` when doing

```
def set_review
  @review = Review.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: it's not nil, it's a relation object: `Couldn't find Review with 'id'=#<Review::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x857fb98>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line returns an `ActiveRecord_Relation` object (sort of an array)

```
@existing_review = Review.of_park(@park.id).by_user(current_user.id)
```

You'll have to do something like this

```
@existing_review = Review.of_park(@park.id).by_user(current_user.id).first
if @existing_review
  redirect_to edit_park_review_path(@park, @existing_review)
end
```